# r xml get following attrib value after specific node

Tags: r, xml-parsing, libxml2, lapply

I am trying to parse all action nodes out of an xml file and add the following atbat num value.  I have a section of an xml file below.  I have the code working to grab all the actions, I just can't figure out how to add the following atbat num to the list/dataframe.  I believe it is a sibling node, not a parent/child node because the actions are not nested under one of the atbat nodes.  The code I'm using is this  I have tried to incorporate following-sibling not equal to action, but couldn't only return errors.  It should pull all values from each action node, append the gameid (it already does this), and append the following atbat num value.

```
url <- "http://gd2.mlb.com/components/game/mlb/year_2015/month_05/day_20/gid_2015_05_20_tbamlb_atlmlb_1/inning/inning_all.xml"


mlb <- read_xml(url)

# get all at-bats ---------------------------------------------------------

atbat <- try(xml_find_all(mlb, "//action"), silent = FALSE)

bind_rows(lapply(atbat, function(y) {
    data.frame(t(xml_attrs(y)), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
})) -> pitch_dat

game_id = substr(url, 66, 95)
pitch_dat$game_id <- game_id

batsdf <- data.frame(pitch_dat)
```

xml example

```
<atbat num="44" b="4" s="0" o="2" start_tfs="004231" start_tfs_zulu="2015-05-21T00:42:31Z" batter="452678" stand="R" b_height="6-0" pitcher="501593" p_throws="L" des="Luis Avilan intentionally walks Asdrubal Cabrera. " des_es="Luis Avilan recibe base por bolas intencional Asdrubal Cabrera. " event_num="333" event="Intent Walk" event_es="Base por Bolas Intencional" play_guid="86cdbf1e-049e-4eb6-9314-85cfb3e6e28a" home_team_runs="1" away_team_runs="1">...</atbat>
<action b="4" s="0" o="2" des="Coaching visit to mound. " des_es="Visita del Instructor a la Lomita" event="Game Advisory" event_es="Aviso en el Juego" tfs="004848" tfs_zulu="2015-05-21T00:48:48Z" player="425784" pitch="4" event_num="334" home_team_runs="1" away_team_runs="1"/>
<action b="0" s="0" o="2" des="Pitching Change: Brandon Cunniff replaces Luis Avilan, batting 9th. " des_es="Cambio de Lanzador: Brandon Cunniff reemplaza a Luis Avilan, bateando noveno. " event="Pitching Substitution" event_es="Cambio de Lanzador" tfs="004904" tfs_zulu="2015-05-21T00:49:04Z" player="594792" pitch="4" event_num="336" home_team_runs="1" away_team_runs="1"/>
<action b="0" s="0" o="2" des="Offensive Substitution: Pinch-hitter Nick Franklin replaces Rene Rivera. " des_es="Sustitución a la ofensiva: bateador emergente Nick Franklin reemplaza a Rene Rivera. " event="Offensive Sub" event_es="Cambio Defensivo" tfs="004924" tfs_zulu="2015-05-21T00:49:24Z" player="545338" pitch="4" event_num="338" home_team_runs="1" away_team_runs="1"/>
<atbat num="45" b="0" s="1" o="3" start_tfs="004934" start_tfs_zulu="2015-05-21T00:49:34Z" batter="545338" stand="L" b_height="6-1" pitcher="594792" p_throws="R" des="Nick Franklin grounds out softly to first baseman Freddie Freeman. " des_es="Nick Franklin batea rodado de out suavemente a primera base Freddie Freeman. " event_num="343" event="Groundout" event_es="Roletazo de Out" home_team_runs="1" away_team_runs="1">...</atbat>
```

[Full XML](http://gd2.mlb.com/components/game/mlb/year_2015/month_05/day_20/gid_2015_05_20_tbamlb_atlmlb_1/inning/inning_all.xml)

What I would like to end up with, the atbatnum field is filled with made up data for example purposes.

```
Variables:
$ b              (chr) "1", "0", "0", "4", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "4", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"
$ s              (chr) "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "2", "2", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"
$ o              (chr) "1", "2", "0", "2", "2", "2", "0", "0", "0", "1", "2", "2", "0", "0", "0", "0", "2"
$ des            (chr) "Coaching visit to mound.  ", "Offensive Substitution: Pinch-hitter Adonis Garcia replaces Williams Perez.  ", "Pitchi...
$ des_es         (chr) "Visita del Instructor a la Lomita", "Sustitución a la ofensiva: bateador emergente Adonis Garcia reemplaza a Williams...
$ event          (chr) "Game Advisory", "Offensive Sub", "Pitching Substitution", "Game Advisory", "Pitching Substitution", "Offensive Sub", ...
$ event_es       (chr) "Aviso en el Juego", "Cambio Defensivo", "Cambio de Lanzador", "Aviso en el Juego", "Cambio de Lanzador", "Cambio Defe...
$ tfs            (chr) "001915", "002757", "003536", "004848", "004904", "004924", "005010", "005949", "010446", "011004", "011539", "011723"...
$ tfs_zulu       (chr) "2015-05-21T00:19:15Z", "2015-05-21T00:27:57Z", "2015-05-21T00:35:36Z", "2015-05-21T00:48:48Z", "2015-05-21T00:49:04Z"...
$ player         (chr) "519306", "611177", "501593", "425784", "594792", "545338", "435064", "542994", "544993", "465674", "430948", "607054"...
$ pitch          (chr) "3", "3", "5", "4", "4", "4", "2", "4", "2", "2", "10", "3", "4", "4", "1", "6", "6"
$ event_num      (chr) "253", "283", "306", "334", "336", "338", "347", "386", "404", "420", "442", "449", "456", "458", "490", "515", "532"
$ home_team_runs (chr) "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2"
$ away_team_runs (chr) "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"
$ play_guid      (chr) NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "c99d1e25-008f-4c46-aff0-d9e9e8548664", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
$ game_id        (chr) "gid_2015_05_20_tbamlb_atlmlb_1", "gid_2015_05_20_tbamlb_atlmlb_1", "gid_2015_05_20_tbamlb_atlmlb_1", "gid_2015_05_20_...
$ atbat_num      (chr)  "1","12","13","24","24","34","35...
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!  Thanks!

Comment: Is this play-by-play data?  You might want to have a look at my package [retrosheet](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/retrosheet/index.html) (shameless self-promotion).  But anyway, is the html you show in the post an example of what you want or what you have?

Comment: @RichardScriven very nice pkg.

Comment: It's an example of what I have to work with, not what I want.  I'll edit the post to show what I'm aiming for.

Comment: @RichardScriven.  I'll definitely have to check that out.

Comment: @RichardScriven your package looks pretty nice, however I can't get current years data.  I realize that's a limitation to retrosheet and not your package.  It's still pretty cool though!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do, I'm there is a better way to do it though.

```
mlb <- read_xml(innallURL)
```

this line grabs the bottom of the innings
    tactions <- try(xml_find_all(mlb, "//bottom"), silent = TRUE)

```
if (inherits(tactions, "try-error") |
    length(tactions) == 0) next

# make a giant data frame -------------------------------------------------

bind_rows(lapply(tactions, function(x) {
```

this line grabs everything under the bottom of the innings
      pitches <- try(xml_find_all(x, "./*"), silent=FALSE)

```
  if (inherits(pitches, "try-error") |
      length(pitches) == 0) return(NULL)

  bind_rows(lapply(pitches, function(y) {
    data.frame(t(xml_attrs(y)), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  })) -> pitch_dat

  pitch_dat

})) -> bats
```

grab and add the gameid

```
game_id = substr(innallURL, 66, 95)
bats$game_id <- game_id
```

create dataframe

```
batsdf <- data.frame(bats)
```

add each loop to batsdf

```
allbats <- bind_rows(batsdf, allbats)

##################################################
#         SEARCH TOP INNING
#
##################################################
```

grab all the tops of each inning
    actions <- try(xml_find_all(mlb, "//top"), silent = TRUE)

```
if (inherits(actions, "try-error") |
    length(actions) == 0) next

# make a giant data frame -------------------------------------------------

bind_rows(lapply(actions, function(x) {
```

grab everything under the tops of each inning
      pitches <- try(xml_find_all(x, "./*"), silent=FALSE)

```
  if (inherits(pitches, "try-error") |
      length(pitches) == 0) return(NULL)

  bind_rows(lapply(pitches, function(y) {
    data.frame(t(xml_attrs(y)), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  })) -> pitch_dat

  pitch_dat

})) -> bats
```

grab game id and add
    game_id = substr(innallURL, 66, 95)
    bats$game_id <- game_id

convert to data frame
    batsdf <- data.frame(bats)
    allbats <- bind_rows(batsdf, allbats)

use zoo library to grab the atbat num from the next line

```
allbats$num <- na.locf(allbats$num, fromLast=TRUE)
```

remove all lines that do not have na in the start_tfs column leaving only the actions

```
bottomAllbats <- subset(allbats, is.na(start_tfs))


##################################################
#         REMOVE COLUMNS WITH ALL NA's
#
##################################################
```

remove all columns left from the pitches and runners nodes where the count of na's equal the number of rows in the data frame leaving only the columns in the actions table where there is data.

```
tactiondf <- bottomAllbats[, colSums(is.na(bottomAllbats)) != nrow(bottomAllbats)]
```